# How do I get an instance of a class at runtime?

Tags: java, class, runtime, instance

I am making a command framework API. People will use my API in their own project.

I have detected all @Command annotations, and when I trigger the command I invoke their attached method.

The issue is I need to be able to either load these classes, or get the live instance. This is because they may have chosen to load the command class themself if they, for example, use a constructor to pass data. Or not.

I've got the former worked out (which works fine):

```
mapping.getMethod().invoke(mapping.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().newInstance(), paramValues);
```

But this errors if a live instance exists. How can I get the the live instance?

This is a tricky situation as I am trying to do this for THEIR classes not mine, so I have a lot less available to me. I'm happy to use reflection or whatever hacky methods you come up with.

Comment: Can the caller pass you the instance they desire? What's the "live" instance for classes that aren't singletons?

Comment: They can, but I'm really trying to go for usability. That is definitely a solution, so it's not the end of the world, but I would REALLY like to do as originally intended if I can!

Comment: In regards to your singleton comment (I see you edited that so didn't include it in my comment): I could also impose this. But I really don't like the idea of imposing on my API users that their command classes must all be singletons.

Comment: Is there any solution involving a class loader maybe?

Comment: @StevenKross - If the caller doesn't pass you an instance, and there can be multiple instances, how would your code know which instance is the specific "live" instance?

Comment: Well I was assuming a well-written method would return a collection of them, which I can then sift through manually.